# Get nested json value using ASP Classic and aspJSON

Tags: arrays, json, vbscript, asp-classic

Good afternoon, I'm using aspJSON (https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON) to analyze a json that I have below:

```
{
   "pedido":1507WSC,
   "destino":"Brasil",
   "Passageiros":[
      {
         "bilhete":150WDE,
         "valor_seguro":0.0,
         "opcionais_bilhete":[
            {
               "tipo":"OET",
               "codigo":1502,
               "nome":"Esportiva",
               "valor":15.00
            }
         ],
         "codigo":528XCV,
      }
   ],
   "opcionais":null,
   "data_viagem":null
}
```

I am using the ASP code below to get some information.

```
Response.LCID = 1043

Dim objVoucher
Dim objJson : Set objJson = New JSONobject

Set objVoucher = objJson.parse(MyJasonTextHere)

Dim Pax

For Each Pax in objVoucher("Passageiros").items
        response.write (Pax.value("bilhete"))
Next
```

The result is **150WDE**. It's correct so far.

However, now I need to get the information contained in the **tipo** parameter that is contained in the **opcionais_bilhete** node.

I've tried it in several ways but I always have an error. How do I get a value from a node that is inside the main json (nested json) in classic asp?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON/wiki

Comment: https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON/issues/79

Comment: Would it not be to use a `For Each` statement to loop through `Pax("opcionais_bilhete").items` as it's a `JSONarray` object?

Comment: I'll try to do it that way, it may be. Thanks.

Comment: Not Works! Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required

Comment: [Works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987734/692942) for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973439/get-nested-json-value-using-asp-classic-and-aspjson#comment107877580_60973439):

> Would it not be to use a `For Each` statement to loop through `Pax("opcionais_bilhete").items` as it's a `JSONarray` object?

This works for me.

```vb
<%
Response.LCID = 1043

Dim objVoucher
Dim objJson : Set objJson = New JSONobject

Set objVoucher = objJson.parse(json)

Dim Pax, Op

For Each Pax in objVoucher("Passageiros").items
  Call Response.Write(Pax.value("bilhete") & "<br />")
  'Loop through the "opcionais_bilhete" JSONarray
  For Each Op in Pax("opcionais_bilhete").items
    Call Response.Write(Op.value("tipo"))
  Next
Next
%>
```

Output:

```
150WDE
OET
```